# print all possible strings of length p that can be formed from the given set

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of characters and a positive integer p, I have to print all possible strings of length p that can be formed from the given set.

```
for eg: if the set is {a,b}
 and the value of p is 2

Output is: aa,ab,ba,bb
```

I know that for a given set of size n, there will be n<sup>p</sup> possible strings of length p.

What is the best method that can be used to print all the possible strings.? I just want an approach to solve.

I'm using C.

Comment: Homework, people. Please no straight answers.

Comment: -1 for no attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach could be to start from an empty string and add characters one by one to it using a recursive function and printing it.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void print_string(char str[],char new_str[],int current_len,int n,int len)
{
    /*
    str=orignal set,
    new_str=empty char array,
    current_len=0(Intially)
    n=no of elements to be used
    len=the value of p given*/
    if(current_len==len)//print string when length is equal to p
    {
        printf("%s\n",new_str);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            new_str[current_len]=str[i];
            print_string(str,new_str,current_len+1,n,len);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char set[]={'a','b'};
    char arr[10]="";
    print_string(set,arr,0,2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
aa
ab
ba 
bb
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to list your strings in lexicographical order. Fastest way (and minimal memory usage) is to implement a function to compute the next string to a given one. Here is some temptative code:

```
char first_char='a';
int n_chars = 2;
int p=2;

char result[100];

int i,j;

/* fill-in first string */
for(i=0;i<p;++i) result[i]=first_char;
result[i]=0; /* string terminator */

printf("%s\n",result); /* print first string */
while(1) {
  /* find last character of result which can be incremented
  for (j=p-1;j>=0 && result[j]!=first_char + n_chars -1;j--);
  if (j<0) break; /* this was the last string */

  result[j]++; /* increment j-th character
  for(j++;j<p;++j) result[j]=first_char; /* reset following chars */

  /* print current string */
  printf("%s\n",result);
}
```

Comment: I think you meant lexicographical order.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a vector, let's call it : string [ p ].
If p is for eg. 7, you will have :
string = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

The index 0, is for the first char, index 1 for the second and so on until N.
for string : "smthing" , you will have : 0 - s , 1 - m, 2-t, 3-h, 4-i, 5-n, 6-g.

You may use a : while ( all elements in string != 'n' ) {
  for the initial string ( string[p]={0} ) you will have : "sssssss" , the first string we built till yes.
you will always add +1 at index each loop and if index = n, you will reset it, like this [0 0 9] -> [0 1 0] if n=9 for exemple.
..and you will have all the posible combination by interpreting the index like i described;
}