# Algorithm for generating size n combinations of k characters

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I need an algorithm which generates all the combinations of size n of k characters.

If for example I have n=1 and k={a,b}, the result should be:

```
a
b
```

If n=3 and k={a,b}, the result should be:

```
a a a
a a b
a b a
a b b
b a a
b a b
b b a
b b b
```

Can someone suggest an algorithm for achieving this?

Thank you!

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: the `length of k` to the power of `n`

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506848/print-all-possible-strings-of-length-p-that-can-be-formed-from-the-given-set/17506889#17506889

Comment: -1 duplicated homework question

Comment: @fordprefect it is not a homework question. I needed to do this in my code, and although the problem and the solution are simple they didn't come to mind, nor could I find the solution by searching the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply map your solution to the values 0 to (|k|^n )-1. The solutions are simply the representation of the number  with base |k|

e.g. k={a,b,c} n=2
Solution is 0,1,2,... 3^2 -1 = 8

```
decimal |  representation in base 3
--------+---------------------------
0       |   00
1       |   01
2       |   02
3       |   10
4       |   11
5       |   12
6       |   20
7       |   21
8       |   22
```

now replace '0' by 'a', '1' by 'b' and '2' by 'c' and you get

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

Comment: I'd really love to see how you do this for k=10, n=100

Comment: converting the number representation to base |n| is a really simple algorithm, so I did not post an implementation here.

Comment: @Nicolas Tyler: What do you mean by `does not work for both his examples`? His k={a,b} n=3 example leads to the numbers 0..2^3-1=7 which correspond to the 8 combinations he posted as desired solution.

Comment: @icepack: make a counting loop from `0 to 10^100-1=`. Of cause you need a language which can represent such big numbers.

Comment: If you are more in functional programming and more memory usage and slower speed is no problem for you, you can also use a recursive approach where you start with n=1 and than recursive extend n by one.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution I was looking for and it's so simple now that I see it. It will work for me, because the numbers I'll have to deal with won't be that large.

Comment: @MrSmith42 the problem here is not with the loop but with memory. Either you map the values (like you did) or generate them in runtime.

Comment: @icepack: With my approach you can generate the combinations on the fly while iterating through the loop. That needs near to no memory. You can even implement it as an Iterator which generates the next combination on demand. It only needs to store the actual number of the last generated one.

Comment: @MrSmith42 You don't need the mapping if you iterate. That's the whole point.

Comment: @icepack: I think we understand different things under the word 'mapping'. I do not mean that there is an actual table for the mapping. I meant a function which translates decimal to a representation of base |k|.

Answer (score 0):

the length of k to the power of n

in java:

```
int combinations = Math.pow(k.length,n);
```

Comment: Yes that's the size of the wanted answer, but generating the combinations is the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.
It's intuitive and I hope it helps you.
Explanation:Pick a character and choose what to put next to it.Do this recursively.

```
 char availablechars[];//In your case this is {a,b}
 int availablechars_size;//This is 2
 void generate(int n,string res)
 {
   if(n==0)
   {
     cout<<"\n"<<res;
     return;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<availablechars_size;i++)
   {
    string t=res;
    t+=availablechars[i];
    t+=" ";
    generate(n-1,t);
   }
 }
```

**Time Complexity**:O(k<sup>n</sup>)

The function call is :

```
 generate(n,"");
```

Comment: It's a bit funny to see your complexity definition. Complexity is usually defined in terms of input parameters, in this case it's `n` and `k`. Your `M` doesn't provide any useful information unless you define it via `n` and `k`. The complexity is `O(k^n)`